# Signals catch with multithread program C

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, signals

I have some issues on a program I'm working on right now.
It does a distributed simulation much like the game of life, using 3 kind of threads: dispatcher (generates tasks), k-workers (performe tasks), and collector (send data to forked process through AF_UNIX).
Forked process is responsable of printing results on screen.

Collector needs to send data every n-iterations, specified by command-line arguments.

So far I got to work all the synchronization part, but the program misses to catch some signals (like SIGUSR2 that I use from dispatcher to tell collector to send data).

What could be the problem?

I'll leave my code [here](http://pastebin.com/M22q128N), just in case anyone is interested to help :-)

Comment: For a single-process, multithreaded application there are better (mostly easier) ways to synchronise then by using signals.

Comment: For example? I'm open to any suggestion

Comment: Mutexes, conditions, semaphores were the objects of choice.

Comment: You can call **only** async-signal-safe functions in a signal handler.  `pthread_cond_signal()` is **not** async-signal-safe.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I forgot that point. Anyway I'm rewriting my concurrent algorithm to make it work minimizing sys override and avoiding signal use.